# I log in with KDM but get a Gnome session, how do I get KDE instead?

Tags: debian, gnome, kde, kdm

I was using console-only version of Debian (amd64) for some time, but I got tired and installed GNOME desktop. Then I installed also KDE-full. `sudo apt-get install kde-full`. I updated default DE to KDE in `/etc/X11/default-display-manadger` (/etc/init.d/kdm) and rebooted. Then I was booted in tty1, and with `sudo /etc/init.d/kdm start` I got GNOME. So, GNOME is somehow interrupting KDE or something like that. How can it be solved? P.S. Searched in Google and got nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KDM is a [display manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_display_manager_(program_type)): it's the program where you type your credentials and get logged in. It happens that both Gnome and KDE provide a display manager, but the choice of display manager is independent from the choice of desktop environment. The desktop environment is a user preference while the display manager is a system preference.

Modern display managers (including KDM and GDM) have a menu where you can select a session type. The default on Debian if you have both Gnome and KDE installed happens to be Gnome. Select KDE in the session menu instead. This choice will be remembered on subsequent logins (in `~/.dmrc`).